# How to display the alt below images in Panels?

Tags: media

I have a drupal site which sells variety of products.
I set a content type for my product and use panel for the layout.
Basically, the text is on left, and images on right
Is there anyway So I can Display the alt text below images because they are very valuable keywords for SEO and customer. 
I can't find the any tokens of node field to import into panel.

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not enough of a Panels user to answer your question, but I would suggest a more proper method of displaying the text in question, because that's not really what alt text is meant for. Additionally, search engines read alt text anyway, so, from an SEO perspective, there is not a need to display it manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you add your images by using content and content type, this might help.

Content type -> one of the list -> manage field

[image]

click on image hyperlink follow by edit tab

[image]

Check Enable Alt field and it wil appear in edit content.

Hope this help.